# Measurable for all Rationals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose the function $f$ is defined on a measurable set $E$ and has the property that $\{x \in E ~|~ f(x) > c \}$ is measurable for each rational number $c$. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

I suspect the answer is affirmative, but I am having trouble proving the theorem. Let $c \in \Bbb{R}$ be irrational. My thought was to try and write $f^{-1}(E \cap (c,\infty))$ as some countable union of sets of the form $\{x \in E ~|~ f(x) > c \}$, but I couldn't see how to do it. The best I could come up with is by noting that there exists a $q \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $q < c$, and then

$$f^{-1} ( E \cap (c, \infty)) = f^{-1} (E \cap ((q,\infty) - (q,c])) = f^{-1}(E \cap (q,\infty)) - f^{-1}(E \cap (q,c])$$

I know that $f^{-1}(E \cap (q,\infty))$ is measurable, but I don't there being any necessity to $f^{-1}(E \cap (q,c])$ being measurable. I could use a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $r$ be a real number and let $c_i\downarrow r$. Then we have
$$
\{ x\in E:f(x)>r\} =\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\{ x\in E:f(x)>c_i\} 
$$
where the right hand side is a union of Borel sets and thus a Borel set.

I leave it up to you to prove that the sets are in fact equal.

Comment: What does "$c_i\downarrow r$" denote?

Comment: A sequence decreasing to r