# $f^{-1}([a,\infty))$ measurable for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $F$ is defined on a measurable set $E$ and for every $c \in \mathbb{Q}$

$f^{-1}([c,\infty))$ is measurable. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

## Attempt

Yes, $f$ is measurable. Let $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then there is a decreasing sequence of rational numbers $q_n$ which converges to $a$. Each $\{x:f(x)>q_n\}_n$ is measurable and ${x:f(x) > q_n}_n \to \{x:f(x)>a\}$ as $n \to \infty$ increasingly. Thus our set is measurable.

Comment: That looks fine. However, it would be more elegant to say that $$\{ f(x) >a\} = \bigcap_n \{ f(x) > q_n \}$$ is a countable intersection of measurable sets, thus it is measurable.

Comment: also, just a nitpick, but you probably want $a\in E\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448047/measurable-for-all-rationals/2448053#2448053